# Sugestões para atualização de aplicação JSE para J2EE

Tags: java, jsf, mvc, jsp

Já a mais de três anos não trabalho com Java para valer, tenho trabalhado com PHP, aprendido e gostado bastante. Na minha opinião, todas as duas linguagens tem muitas vantagens legais de serem incorporadas na outra.

A alguns anos desenvolvi um projeto JSE com Swing para um cliente que a utiliza Standalone em um único computador. Depois de um tempo fiz uma atualização e adicionei o Maven, além disso, esta aplicação foi desenvolvida inicialmente com Hibernate, JasperReports e MySQL.

Enfim, o cliente desta aplicação está me solicitando uma atualização do mesmo, porém só acho viável realizá-la caso eu a mude para o ambiente WEB, ou seja, J2EE. Tenho pouca experiência com JSF e já vi JSP, bem como SpringMVC. Por trabalhar com PHP em uma aplicação grande e completa, utilizando Bootstrap e o framework CodeIgniter, tenho uma noção muito melhor que pode facilitar o meu trabalho na implementação, principalmente no que se refere na integração entre as camadas MVC.

Por isso, pergunto a vocês. Qual seria a melhor tecnologia J2EE a ser adotada para este contexto levando em consideração os meu seguintes quesitos?

- O framework para contrução das views (JSF ou JSP) deve ter boa integração com o Twitter Bootstrap para construção de um design responsivo.
- A exibição de dados de Modelo diretamente nas Views deve ser bem dinâmico, assim como no JSF.
- Algum framework que ofereça funcionalidades automáticas de segurança, como sanitização de campos, SQL injection e etc.

Conto com a ajuda de vocês para me ajudar em minha atualização.

Comment: Por que nao reescreve em php? Uma vez que vc trabalha melhor com ele.

Comment: Realmente, pensei nesta hipótese. Porém a aplicação já é feita em Java, e também possui relatórios bem complexos feitos com o framework JasperReports. Além disso tem também a vontade de aprender ainda mais sobre java.

Comment: No seu lugar eu escolheria trabalhar com o Spring MVC. Se você usar o query params do Hibernate não terá problemas com SQL Injection, para controle de acesso usaria Spring Security.

Comment: @adelmo00 muito bom. Você me sugeriria algo para trabalhar com a interface gráfica, ou seja, geração mais dinâmica das vies?

Comment: Nos projetos eu uso o Tile 2. Procure também por injeção de dependência em Java e Spring Data. O Spring Data já tem métodos do crud prontos e pode te ajudar bastante.

Comment: Muito obrigado @adelmo00, são coisas novas para mim, assim como queria. Vou procurar a respeito.